# Simplifying, printing text instead of boolean value, Python

Tags: python

Using python to grade student scores. Trying to simplify from

```
A = ((float(scptratio)) >= (0.9) and (float(scptratio) <= 1))
B = ((float(scptratio)) >= (0.8) and (float(scptratio) <= (0.89)))

if A == True:
print (studentname, (" has scored an A on the test."))

elif B == True:
print (studentname, (" has scored an B on the test."))

elif C == True:
    print (studentname, (" has scored an C on the test."))
```

etc. to something along the lines of

```
A = (((float(scptratio)) >= (0.9) and (float(scptratio) <= 1)), "A")
B = (((float(scptratio)) >= (0.8) and (float(scptratio) <= (0.89))), "B")

Pass = [A, B, C, D]


if Pass:
    print (studentname, "passed the test with a coefficient of", scptratio, ("scoring a grade of {}".format(Pass)))
elif F:
    print (studentname, "has failed the test.")

else:
    print ("Error! Negative value entered.")
```

How can i get it to print the actual letter score instead of boolean values?

Comment: You really shouldn't name your variables with uppercase letters since they can collide with class names.

Comment: You could massively improve readability by converting `scpratio` to float **once** at the start of the script.

Comment: Thank you, really haven though it through.

Comment: You dont really need to define an upper and lower limit for each grade, since they are consecutive. You could just define a lower limit. You might just make a function that has an chain of if/else checking if the score is lower than `A` else lower than `B` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest making an easily-editable list containing the minimum score required for a specific grade, from high to low:

```
minimum_scores = [("A", 9), ("B", 8), ("C", 7), ("D", 6)]
```

Then go through this list and print the first grade for which the student passed.

```
for grade, score in minimum_scores:
    if float(scptratio) >= score:
        print(studentname, "passed the test with a coefficient of", str(scptratio), "scoring a grade of", grade)
        break
else: #No break hit, so the student didn't pass any of the minimum requirements.
    print(studentname, "has failed the test.")
```